# SQL - Divide single column in multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, select, split

I have the following SQL question:

How to divide a column (text inside) using the SELECT command into two separate columns with split text?

I need to separate the text-data, using the space character.
I know it is better to put an example to make it easy. So:

```
SELECT COLUMN_A FROM TABLE1
```

output:

```
COLUMN_A
-----------
LORE IPSUM
```

desired output:

```
COLUMN_A   COLUMN_B
---------  ----------
LORE       IPSUM
```

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on the consistency of the data - assuming a single space is the separator between what you want to appear in column one vs two:

```
WITH TEST_DATA AS
  (SELECT 'LOREM IPSUM' COLUMN_A FROM DUAL)

SELECT SUBSTR(t.COLUMN_A, 1, INSTR(t.COLUMN_A, ' ')-1) AS COLUMN_A,
       SUBSTR(t.COLUMN_A, INSTR(t.COLUMN_A, ' ')+1) AS COLUMN_B
FROM test_data T;
```

You can also use below query with REGEX:

```
WITH TEST_DATA AS
   (SELECT 'LOREM IPSUM' COLUMN_A FROM DUAL)

SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.COLUMN_A, '[^ ]+', 1, 1) COLUMN_A,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.COLUMN_A, '[^ ]+', 1, 2) COLUMN_B
FROM test_data T;
```

Oracle 10g+ has regex support, allowing more flexibility depending on the situation you need to solve.  It also has a regex substring method...

**EDIT:**
3 WORDS SPLIT:

```
WITH TEST_DATA AS
  (SELECT 'LOREM IPSUM DIMSUM' COLUMN_A FROM DUAL)

 SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.COLUMN_A, '[^ ]+', 1, 1) COLUMN_A,
     REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.COLUMN_A, '[^ ]+', 1, 2) COLUMN_B,
     REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.COLUMN_A, '[^ ]+', 2, 3) COLUMN_C
 FROM test_data T;
```

Reference:

- [SUBSTR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php)
- [INSTR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php)

Comment: Hello @Nisha and thanks for your answer! I did not think to use the SUBSTR/INSTR to manage that so thanks! Just one more question: If I have 3 words to split? How can we do that?

Comment: Use this Query for 3 words split. Refer Edit

Comment: Thank you very much Nisha, can I ask you what the first number in -- '[^ ]+', 1, 1 -- stay for? I mean you put 1,1 and than 2. Why these?

Comment: May be this link would help <http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/regular-expressions-support-in-oracle.php>

Answer (score 2):

The solution can be generalized using a counter and the `PIVOT` operator, the counter to get the word number and the `PIVOT` to change rows to columns

```
WITH Counter (N) AS (
  SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX(regexp_count( COLUMN_A, ' ')) + 1
                       FROM   Table1)
)
SELECT Word_1, Word_2, Word_3, Word_4
FROM   (SELECT t.COLUMN_A
             , c.N N
             , REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.COLUMN_A, '[^ ]+', 1, c.N) Word
        FROM   Table1 t
               LEFT JOIN Counter c ON c.N <= regexp_count( COLUMN_A, ' ') + 1) b
       PIVOT
       (MAX(Word) FOR N IN (1 Word_1, 2 Word_2, 3 Word_3, 4 Word_4)) pvt
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/808da/39)</kbd>

But that have a fixed columns list in the `PIVOT` definition, to really have a general query a dynamic pivot or a `PIVOT XML` is needed

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Rough (Tag_Id,Status_ , new_)                      
        WITH TEST_DATA AS              
             (SELECT regexp_replace('&data' ,'\s+',' ') COLUMN_A FROM DUAL)
                 SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (REGEXP_SUBSTR (t.COLUMN_A, '[^-]+', 1, LEVEL), '[^ ]+', 1, 1) AS Col1,
                       REGEXP_SUBSTR (REGEXP_SUBSTR (t.COLUMN_A, '[^-]+', 1, LEVEL), '[^ ]+', 1, 2) AS Col2,
                            REGEXP_SUBSTR (REGEXP_SUBSTR (t.COLUMN_A, '[^-]+', 1, LEVEL), '[^ ]+', 1, 3) AS Col3
                                FROM test_data T    
                                     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (REGEXP_REPLACE (t.COLUMN_A, '[^-]+')) + 1;
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answwer to explain what you changed and why this will fix the question ?