# Split random data in a column with semi colon delimiter into few columns in oracle

Tags: oracle, split, oracle10g

Can you help me to solve this with simple query in oracle 10g?

I have referenced this question from : [SQL - Divide single column in multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033336/sql-divide-single-column-in-multiple-columns)

But, how if the amount of commas are not defined?

Example (edited)

1. 1st Row: Black, Blue, White
2. 2nd Row: Blue, White
3. 3rd Row: Blue, White, Black, Brown

Comment: What output would you like from that input? (Hint: perhaps you want Blue, White, NULL, NULL for the second row - but that should be the output from `'Blue, White, , , '` - not from `'Blue, White'`.) You probably meant 1st Row (etc.), not 1st Column...?

Comment: where is your data?

Comment: @mathguy, thanks for the fast support. Yeah, you are right, I mean 1st row, not 1st column.The output: 1st column Blue, 2nd column White, 3rd column Blank, 4th column Blank. But, the data that I have doesn't have comma in the last row.

Comment: @Ersin Gulbahar, my data already attached above.

Comment: @Sarah - do you know ahead of time the max. number of values in each string? (Such as 4 in your example.) That will also be the number of columns in the output, and if that number is not known beforehand, you can't do this in standard SQL. You will need to use "dynamic SQL", which may sound like "SQL" but is in fact quite different (and generally not recommended for a variety of reasons).

Comment: @mathguy I don't know the maximum number. How can I get that dynamic SQL? Is there any clue for this one? In php, I can use explode to split the data easilly.

Comment: Don't ask for dynamic SQL. Start over. WHY do you need the output to be in separate columns? Wouldn't it suffice to get an output where, for each input string, you get a few ROWS (not columns), showing the string (or a unique identifier for it), the position, and the token? In a database that is by far the more efficient and the more common to structure data. Forget php; php is for one thing, SQL is for an entirely different thing.

Comment: @mathguy Another system need this data to be separated data in each column.